# passing selectedindex of one dropdown as an mvc parameter of a second dropdown on same razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I have the following dropdown:

```
<select id="coursedd" name="courseid" style="height:40px; font-size:18px;">
      <option value="0" id ="defaultcid" class ="choosefilter" >----Please Select Course----</option>
      @foreach (var course in Model.GetCourseList())
      {
        <option value="@course.CourseID" id ="courseid" class ="choosefilter" >@course.Name </option>
      }
      </select>
```

When something is selected from this dropdown I want to populate a second dropdown with information relating to the selected item in the first dropdown. How can I retrieve the value of the first dropdowns selected index and pass it into the GetCourseSectionByCourseID() method as shown below:

```
<select id="coursesectiondd" name="coursesectionid" style="height:40px; font-size:18px;">
      <option value="null" id ="defaultcs" class ="choosefilter" >----Please Select Course Section----</option>
      @foreach (var courseSection in Model.GetCourseSectionsByCourseID(**??**))
      {
        <option value="@courseSection.CourseSectionID" id ="coursesectionid" class ="choosefilter" >@courseSection.Title </option>
      }
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a cascading dropdown plugin, either roll your own and perform a get when the first dropdownlist changes, or use a plugin like this

http://www.ryanmwright.com/2010/10/13/cascading-drop-down-in-jquery/